# Unable to brew link qt

Tags: macos, qt, homebrew

So I just installed `qt` via brew in Mac OS X. It was unable to link it however.
When I try to run `brew link qt` or `brew link --overwrite qt` I get back the following:

```
tonybeninate$ brew link --overwrite qt
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4... Warning: Could not link qt. Unlinking...

Error: Directory not empty - /usr/local/opt/qt
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I've also tried running `brew link -n qt` and removing any files/dirs that were conflicting to no avail.

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix this by removing all the contents of qt including hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew cleanup`.

Even with above command, you might get similar error. To fix it, change permissions with

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

If you are on Mac High Sierra, use

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

[Follow this post for more permissions related changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)

Once permissions are done, try `brew cleanup` and your command `brew link --overwrite qt`