# How to avoid "cannot load such file -- utils/popen" from homebrew on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew

I'm getting an error when I run  `brew` in the terminal:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- utils/popen (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

These are my gem settings:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - universal-darwin-13
- GEM PATHS:
  - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - /Users/ronaldkwan/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
```

Comment: Can you add information? What command did you exactly run?

Comment: i just typed "brew"into unix

Comment: What happens when you run `brew doctor` ?

Comment: same error.
here are my env gem settings

Comment: Looks like your ruby installation is incomplete. Try reinstalling or using another ruby installation.

Comment: Simple way to solve this please check my answer below. It worked for me @RonaldKwan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29477604/115363

Comment: Proper way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260396/2267723

Answer (score 804):

### Original Answer

The problem mainly occurs after updating OS X to El Capitan (OS X 10.11) or macOS Sierra (macOS 10.12).

This is because of file permission issues with El Capitan’s or later macOS's [new SIP process](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/what-is-sip-in-osx-10-11-el-capitan/). Try changing the permissions for the `/usr/local` directory:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

If it still doesn't work, use these steps inside a terminal session and everything will be fine:

```sh
cd /usr/local/Homebrew
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

If `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew` doesn't work, try `/usr/local/Homebrew`. The problem might be that Homebrew is outdated.

### Apr 2021 Update

The command above doesn't work for macOS High Sierra or above, as explained in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228#issuecomment-332679274). You have to run this instead:

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Comment: I had the problem caused by El Capitan update. This solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Same here, upgrade to El Capitan broke it, I had to reset the permissions first and then run the git commands and brew update worked. Thanks.

Comment: This is right answer if you are facing that problem after upgrading to El Capitan :)

Comment: Worked for me on Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: Had this issue after upgrading to **macOS Sierra**.
This solved it, thanks!
Though, changing permissions on `/usr/local` doesn't seem to be required now.

"Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you can
return `/usr/local` to its default ownership with:
  `sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local`"

Comment: @CodeAlchemist yea, but for the update process it did require ownership of /usr/local, then after you're done you can change it back to root:wheel

Comment: Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you canreturn /usr/local to its default ownership with: sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local

Comment: This works for me. Essentially, it changed the group name from 'wheel' to 'admin' for new os version.

Comment: Second method worked for me. I just needed to find where `HOMEBREW` directory was located. In my case: `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew`

Comment: Second solution did the trick. New version of homebrew no longer needs ownership of `/usr/local`.

Comment: Did not work for **High Sierra** anymore, s. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228#issuecomment-332679274:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Comment: /usr/local can no longer be chown'd in High Sierra. Instead use

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: Fixed but path was: 
cd /usr/local/Homebrew

Comment: Fixed for me on ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 379):

First, open a terminal session and run:

```
cd /usr/local/
git status
```

to see if Homebrew is clean.

If it's dirty, run:

```
git reset --hard && git clean -df
```

then

```
brew doctor
brew update
```

If it's still broken, try this in your session:

```
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
```

This will force Homebrew to use Ruby 1.8 from the system's installation.

Comment: Probably a good answer, but BTW I get other errors when running both commands give (I mention incase anyone wants to cover this further scenario): - rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current: Operation not permitted

Comment: I simply reinstalled homebrew with a fresh version and it started working. Check homebrew homepage with the link to install, and when you try it it will complain that homebrew is already installed and teach you how to uninstall.

Comment: So, uninstalling/reinstalling got Homebrew working again for me. It also deleted everything it had installed, basically trashing my system. So not a great solution.

Comment: If you're getting errors with ruby and you're using RVM, try issuing `rvm use system` to ensure you're using Mac OS X's ruby when running `brew update`

Comment: Note that the default Ruby on recent versions of OS X is 2.0, not 1.8.

Comment: What does "to see if Homebrew is clean." means? and why it is at /usr/local/?

Comment: This method worked for me. I still had to change the permission on /usr/local before it would work. After `brew update` finished it informed me it no longer needed the permissions on /usr/local so I could change it back.

Comment: vineet kapoor's trick above did not work for my macOS High Sierra, but this one worked!

Comment: This is an outdated answer, so use it carefully. Apple's pre-installed Ruby version periodically changes so you'll have to modify the commands to account for those changes.

Answer (score 83):

Uninstall homebrew:

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Then reinstall

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Warning: This script will remove: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/** - thks [benjaminsila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971736/benjaminsila)

Comment: I run an uninstall of Homebrew and then a reinstall. Fixed the issue. @OsTa

    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

Warning: This script will remove:
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/

Comment: Sort of a shotgun approach but this worked more easily than trying to manage file permissions...

Comment: Worked for me On a system upgraded to 10.12 (Sierra), after the uninstall/reinstall I was able to run 'brew doctor' and followed the instructions there to fix a few permissions issues.  Working fine now

Comment: After a hard drive crash my underlying git repository was corrupted and while git reset would therefore not work, un-/reinstalling did. However, I had to reinstall all my installed packages.

Answer (score 27):

In my case I just needed to **remove** Homebrew's executable using:

```
sudo rm -f `which brew`
```

Then **reinstall** Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: In case you get stuck after this in brew install / uninstall loop, use following link - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44460

Comment: Did you get this meesage trying the 2nd command (which seems to be an indication something has gone wrong, though not an error)? - The current contents of /usr/local are bin Cellar CODEOFCONDUCT.md CONTRIBUTING.md etc Frameworks git include lib Library LICENSE.txt opt Qt4.7 README.md share SUPPORTERS.md var .git .gitignore

Comment: @PandaWood no, i didn't. what the content of the error message that you depicting with 'this message' in your comment?

Comment: @deeperx Everything after the "-". In the end, I had to uninstall brew and reinstall again

Comment: @PandaWood Do you use correct commas? Can you copy paste it here directly?

Answer (score 24):

After updating to El Capitan, `/usr/local` has `root:wheel` rights.

Change the rights back to the user using:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

and:

```
brew doctor && brew update
```

This helped me to get Homebrew working again.

Comment: isn't it quite dangerous?

Comment: Permissions to `/usr/local` were changed in the OS for security reasons - so, just because you've "returned rights as before" doesn't mean it's a good thing to do.

Answer (score 8):

First I executed:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Then:

```
cd $(brew --prefix) && git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: FYI, my Homebrew install was at `/usr/local/Homebrew/` so I had to use `cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew`.

Answer (score 3):

This issue should be fixed in the newest version of Homebrew. Try reinstalling it, which is described on the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) home page.

Answer (score 1):

To me it feels like you have missing header files for popen, which is a C system library.

Check if you have installed xcode successful with the command line tools and have accepted the license.

See this thread for more information: [How to install Xcode Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools)

Answer (score 0):

To restore your Homebrew setup try this:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f && git reset --hard && git pull
```