# brew on OSX 10.10.1 not working, ruby kernel_require error

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I recently updated my Mac's copy of OSX from 10.6 to 10.10. Everything seems to be working fine except for brew.

```
my_mac:local my_user$ brew install wget
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- global (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Since brew is based on Ruby I believe there's some problem with the system's install of Ruby, but I'm not sure how to approach it. I've tried to re-install the most recent version of Ruby and then Homebrew, but when Homebrew gets to

```
brew cleanup
```

It throws the same Ruby error.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx Have you tried what they suggest there?

Comment: Try `cd /usr/local; git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: Have you tried `brew update`

Comment: @MarcoPrins I did, it did not work. It resulted in the same Ruby error.

Comment: @TimSmith Unfortunately I get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem too and the problem was corrupted permissions:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ find . -mindepth 1 -user root
```

If any files or directories related to homebrew show up, you should use `chown` to fix the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

it turned to be permission problem.
Here is the command I used to fix the problem based on the answer from quaestor

```
$ cd /usr/local<br>
$ find . -mindepth 1 -user root -exec chown *xxx* {} \ ;
```

Where *xxx* is the user you want to change to.
You may want to only do chown for directories related to brew.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned it is because of corrupted permissions
You can fix it using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

It changes the permissions of /usr/local directory.