# React Native - Failed to build DependencyGraph:Cannot read property 'root' of null

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, react-native

I'm trying to get React Native to run their hello world app (AwesomeProject) for the first time, and I'm getting this error in the console:

`Failed to build DependencyGraph: Cannot read property 'root' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null
    at index.js:16:60
    at tryCallOne (/Users/Eduardo/Documents/Code/Personal/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/Eduardo/Documents/Code/Personal/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/Eduardo/Documents/Code/Personal/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
~
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window`

First of all I'm a mobile developer (native ios and android) and I know squad about node.

I followed the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) page of React Native, got npm installed with `npm install` and `npm install -g`

When I try to start the node server alone, with `node server` I get this:

```
$ node server
module.js:341
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Eduardo/Documents/Code/Personal    /ReactNative/AwesomeProject/server'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:141:18)
at node.js:933:3`
```

Here's a screenshot of what I get in the iOS emulator, and the console when trying to run the app:

[image]

For what's worth, I'm running this on a Mac OS 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.2, and NativeScript creates a simple app without issues.

Any suggestions on what to do on this?

I currently just want to get my feet wet with React Native.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `brew uninstall watchman` and `brew install watchman`

Comment: Hey that worked! Wanna make it an answers so I can log it as resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `brew uninstall watchman` and `brew install watchman`

Comment: FYI this actually ended up solving it for me. El Capitan is the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx#answer-35495897