# I can't install zsh with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, zsh

OS X El Capitan version 10.11.2

I attempted `brew update`, but this error message is displayed.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I also attempted `brew install zsh`, but the above message is displayed.

Please let me know how to fix this error message.

Comment: Looks like your version of ruby is too old or your install of brew is broke.

Comment: Your version of Ruby is fine. Does the `brew update` error happens again if you run `brew update` a second time?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. although brew was working fine with me before. i'm guessing it happened after i upgraded my system to El Capitan.

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer which worked for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495897/1354137

> The problem mainly occurs after updating OS X to El Capitan (OS X 10.11). This is mainly because of file permission issues with file El Capitan’s [new SIP process](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/what-is-sip-in-osx-10-11-el-capitan/). Try changing permissions of */usr/local* directory.
>
> ```
> $ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
> ```
>
> If it still doesn't work, use following steps and everything will be fine. This may be because homebrew is not updated.
>
> ```
> 1. open terminal  
> 2. $ cd /usr/local  
> 3. $ git reset --hard  
> 4. $ git clean -df
> 5. $ brew update
> ```