# Cannot update brew in MAC OS X el capitan and keep getting a Load error with `require`

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am not sure why this is happening but I cannot update brew in my MAC OS X El Capitan. I did:

`brew update`

and got:

```
warning: unable to unlink CONTRIBUTING.md: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink SUPPORTERS.md: Permission denied
fatal: cannot create directory at '.github': Permission denied
```

to go over that issue I sudoed the above command but got further issues:

```
sudo brew update
Password:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

now whenever I do brew install I get:

```
brew update

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

in fact, it seems that whenever I do anything, like just type `brew` it gets the same message. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: this is probably a super hacky solution but I completely uninstalled homebrew and re-installed it. To uninstall read: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-uninstall-Homebrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [homebrew not working on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx)

Comment: Homebrew has been updated to address the problem of `/usr/local` ownership. If you haven't updated Homebrew in a while, follow the steps outlined by @bfontaine below. Once updated, you may revert ownership back to `root:wheel` by running `sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local` and, continue using and updating Homebrew without worrying about file ownership.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You shouldn’t use `sudo` with Homebrew. First run the following to ensure you own everything under `/usr/local`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Alternative command for newer macOS version:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Then reset your Homebrew repo to a clean state:

```
cd /usr/local && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

It should fix your issues.

(replace `/usr/local` with `$(brew --prefix)` if you installed Homebrew elsewhere)

Comment: I ran `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` but the terminal outputted nothing. What was I suppose to see?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to change ownership to a user in `/usr/local`? It seems very wrong to me even though it may work.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen what do you mean?

Comment: @CharlieParker `/usr` is on *NIX owned by `root` because it is for all users, and `${HOME}` by the user. Normally there are ways to install it user local within `${HOME}`, otherwise use `sudo` to install it worldwide in `/usr/local`.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen Yes I’m sure; this is the default location for Homebrew. You can install it in another prefix (e.g. `~/.brew`) but some things might not install correctly.

Comment: @bfontaine Homebrew should do something about that.

Comment: @totoro Well it allows you to install it somewhere else; it can’t really fix software that breaks if not installed under `/usr/local`.

Comment: so is running `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` not the right thing to do? I am confused.

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes it is. This is the only time you’ll need to use `sudo`; don’t run `brew` commands with `sudo`.

Comment: @CharlieParker You can do it, it just violates the basic file system layout idea of *NIX. You can google about that.

Comment: Note that if you’re uncomfortable doing that you can still install Homebrew elsewhere, e.g. in `~/.brew` or `~/.homebrew` (but it’s not officially supported). Homebrew targets mostly people with their own computer so installing personal stuff under `/usr/local` is not an issue.

Comment: @totoro I don't even know what I am suppose to be googling. Ownership of `urs/local`?

Comment: @CharlieParker `unix filesystem layout` -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard.

Comment: I found this in the [Homebrew FAQ in Github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-prefer-i-install-to-usrlocal), which I think is relevant to this answer:
"**Why does Homebrew prefer I install to `/usr/local`?... 3. It’s safe**
Apple has left this directory for us. Which means there is no `/usr/local` directory by default, so there is no need to worry about messing up existing tools."

Comment: You may also need `brew update` after that to fix stuff.

Comment: Suggestion worked great with one correction - homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local.