# brew - permission denied

Tags: permissions, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, permission-denied

My system is OSX 10.11.6.

I'm running into this error:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `read': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/terminal-notifier-1.6.0.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `block in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `find_all'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `matching_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:277:in `to_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:46:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I have tried running 
`brew doctor` but I end up with the exact same error.

I have tried the solution in here: [Cannot update brew in MAC OS X el capitan and keep getting a Load error with `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120545/cannot-update-brew-in-mac-os-x-el-capitan-and-keep-getting-a-load-error-with-re). I have also tried reinstalling brew and I end up with the same error. Even if I type in `brew`, I get the same error. However, when I type `brew update` it will tell me that `Already up-to-date`.

I type in `brew cleanup` I get the same error.

What is wrong? Is it some permission issue?

Comment: ack - I ran into this error today as well, brew and gem both borked. I'm running 10.12.3 - thought it might have something to do with running beta versions of Xcode, but looks like it's probably not given your version of macOS.

Weird things I've done: 1. using Xcode beta, 2. accidentally install Jekyll using sudo? 3. not much else - I'm on a clean work-provided MBP.

Comment: Were you able to just `chmod` that folder `/System/Library/Frameworks`?

Comment: The permissions for `specifications.rb` were:

`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  68489 13 Nov  2013 specification.rb`

So I don't know how I could chmod to anything more useful.

Comment: My ruby also mysteriously started working again. I restarted the whole system (which sort of crashed/locked up a bit while doing so), and still had the error, then after closing terminal and opening it again, it suddenly seemed to work again. Weird - still can't figure out what would cause this. Would be interesting to hear if other users have this specific issue and gather more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. File "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/terminal-notifier-1.6.0.gemspec" has invalid permissions by some reason (read only for owner, not for group). It can be fixed by just adding read permission to group for this file like:

```
sudo chmod g+r /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/terminal-notifier-1.6.0.gemspec
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My ruby mysteriously started working again. I'm not sure if I did something like that to the folder, but it was probably like that (i.e. `chmod [folder path]`.