# Pod install no permission

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to install react native firebase starter kit on a virtual machine running macOS 10.3 on windows 10. I'm totally new to macOS.

I started with cloning it then following the instructions: cd react-native-firebase-starter npm install cd ios then pod install (already installed cocoapods with sudo gems)

when i run pod install this error occurs:

> #### Command
>
> `/usr/local/bin/pod install`
>
> #### Report
>
> - What did you do?
> - What did you expect to happen?
> - What happened instead?
>
> #### Stack
>
> `CocoaPods : 1.5.3
>           Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
>       RubyGems : 2.5.2
>           Host : Mac OS X 10.13.5 (17F77)
>          Xcode : 9.4 (9F1027a)
>            Git : git version 2.15.1 (Apple Git-101) Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
>   Repositories :`
>
> #### Plugins
>
> `cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2 cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
>   cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0 cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
>   cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1 cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`
>
> #### Podfile
>
> ```ruby
>
> ## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'RNFirebaseStarter' do   # Uncomment the next line if you're
>   using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks   #
>   use_frameworks!
>
> # Pods for RNFirebaseStarter
>
> # Required by RNFirebase   pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
>
> # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't
>   be using.   pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Auth',
>   '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Crash', '~> 5.3.0'   pod
>   'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 5.3.0'
>   pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Firestore',
>   '~> 5.3.0'   # pod 'Firebase/Invites', '~> 5.3.0'   pod
>   'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~>
>   5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.3.0'   pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.5'   pod
>   'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.4'
>
> end ```
>
> #### Error
>
> `` Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -
>   /react-native-firebase-starter/ios/Pods
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in
>   `mkdir'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in
>   `fu_mkdir'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in
>   `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in
>   `reverse_each'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in
>   `block in mkdir_p'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in
>   `each'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in
>   `mkdir_p'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb:58:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:184:in
>   `new'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:184:in
>   `sandbox'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:140:in
>   `installer_for_config'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:38:in
>   `run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in
>   `run' /Users/zolz/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in
>   `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>' ``
>
> ――― TEMPLATE END
>   ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
>
> [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
>
> Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Permission+denied+%40+dir_s_mkdir+-+%2Freact-native-firebase-starter%2Fios%2FPods&type=Issues
>
> If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above,
>   on: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
>
> Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to
>   properly submit a ticket:
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
>
> Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
>
> Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods... Found no similar
>   issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
>   https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

I already tried:

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

but it says directory not found.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755885/brew-permission-denied#41935559 maybe you can find something useful...

Comment: i tried but the problem is that it also says no such file or directory. I looked in Library/Caches there's no cocoapods folder even after reinstalling cocoapods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be Privilege Read only of the project and cocoapods can create folder Pod.

Try `chmod 755 /react-native-firebase-starter/ios` will give permission to create folder Pod

or clone react-native-firebase-starter on folder with permission read & write

Comment: i tried the command but didn't work, BUT i cloned it to a folder in /users and worked.. THANKS A LOT