# Brew - cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I need help getting brew setup.  I have tried reinstalling brew and ruby, but I feel like I am just making things worse.

Some information:
 OS X El Capitan V. 10.11.5

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15.5.0]

$ which -a ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

When I try to update brew:

```
$ brew update
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
```

When I try to install ruby:

```
$ rvm install ruby
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Ben/.rvm/log/1467344813_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789161/4459422

Please let me know what other information is needed to solve this problem, and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think you should try reinstalling ruby.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone reading this answers for me its not related to ruby. At least for me the answer is on the [homebrew forum](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/missing-file-homebrew-dead/5657) [SMillerDev](https://discourse.brew.sh/u/SMillerDev) answer.

First try run:

```
brew update-reset
```

if that does not work run:

```
cd $(brew --repo)
git add .
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

hope this can help someone else.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: Life saver you are

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling ruby and to do so, type in following commands:

```
rvm fix-permissions

rvm reinstall 2.3.1
```

Comment: I got `$ rvm uninstall 2.3.1
ruby-2.3.1 - #already gone`
and then the same output as the install above

Comment: Same output, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This command screwed me up: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789161/4459422

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
```

I was using version 2.0 so updated to

```
 sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually install `brew` with system Ruby that ships with OSX. There shouldn't be any need to install Ruby from RVM to install brew.

Which version of OSX this is btw? And which version of ruby is system ruby? Also try `brew doctor` .

Comment: Please  post this as a comment.

Comment: brew doctor gives same output.  OS X El Capitan V. 10.11.5.

Comment: First try `rvm use system` which will make sure you are using system ruby. Better yet, remove rvm from PATH and your shell, since you can always install it after you have installed brew.