# compiling mpic++ no longer works after upgrading my mac

Tags: c++, macos

I have a build script for c++ look like:

mpic++ main.cpp tools.cpp treeofdevil.cpp solver.cpp periodicfunction.cpp  -o ising -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi60  -lpthread -lm -Wall -m64 -fPIE -fexceptions -frounding-math -O2 -I/Library/gurobi604/mac64/include/ -I/usr/local/include/ -I. -L/Library/gurobi604/mac64/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization

Before I upgrade my mac from OSX 10.9 Maverick ->  OSX El Capitan, Everything works fine in MAC OSX 10.9.... However, after upgrade, when I try to compile in the same way.. I get the error...

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iomanip:39,
                 from common.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:13:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iostream:39,
                 from tools.h:13,
                 from tools.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iostream:39,
                 from treeofdevil.h:13,
                 from treeofdevil.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from solver.cpp:1:0:
solver.h:16:20: fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <unistd.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/iostream:39,
                 from periodicfunction.h:13,
                 from periodicfunction.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.4/include/c++/4.8.4/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
                   ^
```

What could I do? Thank you.

Any help?

trying to update brew results in:

```
myname-MacBook-Pro:ising1 myname$ sudo brew update
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
myname-MacBook-Pro:ising1 myname$ 
myname-MacBook-Pro:ising1 myname$ sudo brew doctor
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
myname-MacBook-Pro:ising1 myname$ sudo brew upgrade
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

**2nd update:**
I reinstall homebrew, but everything wrong is still there, so I followed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6WuGENLF18
to reinstall gnu compilers...

now the error looks like:

```
:19086:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
:5054:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
:5059:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
:5959:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
:6196:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your compiler. It's usually gets broken after OS version upgrade.

This commands should help:

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade
```

Also for brew to work on El Capitan you may need to reset /usr/local owner to you and disable system integrity protection `csrutil disable`

Comment: Look at the answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx

Comment: Thanks.... However, I still got some issue... do you know what could I do? Thank you.

Comment: Try to run `brew doctor` again and do whatever it will ask