# Can't install brew

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, homebrew, macos-sierra

I ran this in Terminal:

```
brew install libsndfile
```

Which gave this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 21: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

So in Terminal, [I ran steps 1-5 as suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx/35495897):

```
1. open terminal  
2. $ cd /usr/local/Library/Homebrew  
3. $ git reset --hard  
4. $ git clean -df
5. $ brew update
```

And this is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

How can I get the command `brew install libsndfile` to work?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing was asked in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1071). The cause of your problem is that you have a very old version of Homebrew installed that still relies on Ruby 1.8, which has been replaced by Ruby 2.0 in macOS 10.10.

If you check the issue, you'll find two slightly different solutions. The one that worked for the person who opened the original issue is running these command in a terminal:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Afterwards, you can run `brew upgrade` to update the installed packages (might take some time).