# brew install php55-intl fails, Cant Install Composer

Tags: php, macos, npm, homebrew

I'm trying to install npm install && grunt, however it tells me that I need composer. I'm trying to install composer but that's dependent on php55.

I've tried brew install php55, php55-intl, php56, php56-intl, etc.

I am reading the instructions from here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

It states that for a Mac I should simply use brew commands:

> brew update brew tap 
>   homebrew/homebrew-php 
>   brew tap homebrew/dupes
>   brew tap homebrew/versions
>   brew install php55-intl #fails here
>   brew install homebrew/php/composer

I am getting the following error:

> brew install php55-intl
>   ==> Installing dependencies for php55-intl: php55, icu4c
>   ==> Installing php55-intl dependency: php55
>   ==> Downloading http://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.15.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror Already
>   downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php55-5.5.15
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.15 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d -- checking for png_write_image in -lpng... yes If configure fails try
>   --with-xpm-dir= checking for fabsf... yes checking for floorf... yes configure: error: GD build test failed. Please check the
>   config.log for details.
>
> READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
>   If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
>   https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-php/issues
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': Class is not a module (TypeError)  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:390:in
>   `<class:HTTP>'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:384:in`
>   '    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:25:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/https.rb:21:in`
>   '    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:308:in `open'
>     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:350:in`issues_matching'
>     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:378:in `issues_for_formula'
>     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:171:in`fetch_issues'
>     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:167:in `issues'  from
>   /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:207:in`dump'   from
>   /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:158:in `rescue in <main>'  from
>   /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:66:in`'

Does anyone know another work around? I've tried curl commands but they never run, and I can't run the exe on my mac.

Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't use brew to install your PHP version you can just install composer without brew. Download the .phar and move it to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution:

- Upgrade to the latest version of XCode
- Make sure you reinstall XCode CLT: `xcode-select --install`
- Update your formulae: `brew update`
- Remove zlib: `brew rm zlib`
- Install / reinstall php55: `brew install php55` (as zlib is a dependency, it will be reinstalled)

Followed by `brew install composer`

Found here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/610

I needed to update my Xcode, and then everything ran.

Comment: You may have to do this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions