# Sudo chown mistake?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, chown

I have been trying to install Homebrew on my Mac but ran into permission problems since my user is not an administrator.

I followed the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16450503/4909923

```
su -l admin
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

Now I'm concerned that I have wrongfully changed the ownership of these folders to a specific user. Will it impact my normal user negatively?

> changing ownership of /usr/local to a specific user is not a solution. It is a terrible hack and a workaround if you have a single user system. But then you might as well just chown -R / $USER:$USER –  fijiaaron Jan 23

If this was a stupid thing to do, how do I restore it to normal?

It should probably look like the image with /lib/ which is another folder in /usr/, with `system Read & Write` and `wheel Read Only`.

[image: /usr/local]
[image: /Library/Caches/Homebrew]
[image: another folder in /usr/]

It should probably look like this (another folder in /usr/):

Comment: My `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` directory is owned by root, and `/usr/local` is owned by an admin user on my computer. Both have `rwxrwxr-x` permissions. As long as your permissions are set to work with multiple users on your computer you should be fine. Running `brew doctor` should inform you if there are any severe issues.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks, but if I want to restore it to the way it was (factory settings), do you know how I can do that?

Comment: AFAIK, the way I have it is factory settings.

Comment: @AaronBrager Would you like to show me the terminal commands for setting the folders to your settings? Sorry if I'm asking for too much, but got a bit paranoid that I've messed up the /usr/local folder.

Comment: I'm not convinced anything is wrong with your current installation. But you can use `chown` exactly as in your above example, with different users if you want to switch the ownership, and `chmod` to change the permissions (which you probably won't need to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the permissions I mentioned in the comment should be fine, but if you want to be sure everything is set at its default, you can [uninstall Homebrew using this script](https://superuser.com/a/203740/266885) and then reinstall it from scratch.

You can also follow [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/295772/266885) for resetting the permissions.

Comment: It seems like sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/local did the trick, thanks very much! That changes the owners. Then changed permissions with chmod on the Get Info tab in Yosemite.