# trying to run "brew uninstall node"

Tags: node.js

because my npm and node are giving me grief and I want to rinstall them.

Here is the message I get:

`Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h`

what's with the Permissions denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the permissions and/or ownership records can get messed up. Try following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) or running the uninstall again with `sudo`.