# PHP and MySQL permission problems after changing /usr/local permissions (osx)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, permissions, chown

I couldn't install a library with brew, so I followed this SO answer : [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions/16450503#16450503)

I changed permissions on `/usr/local` with this command :

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Now I have this warning from PHP :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.54.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so
Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

And this error from SQL :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1017 Can't find file:  './imagetransfer/newsroom.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction ? I don't know if I should change permissions on `/usr/local` again (and in that case, which rights I should use) or if I'd better change permissions elsewhere.