# how to fix Homebrew permissions? (extra tough case)

Tags: permissions, homebrew

I'm trying to fix my permissions for OSX Homebrew, but I'm still getting

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/opt
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

I followed the instructions at [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) which suggests doing this:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local 
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew 
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

From https://superuser.com/questions/254843/cant-install-brew-formulae-correctly-permission-denied-in-usr-local-lib, I also tried this:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

And I also ran this Ruby script: https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518 like this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/raw/768518/fix_homebrew.rb)
```

And from http://mascarenhas.us/blog/2013/05/25/osx-tip-fix-permissions-issue-during-homebrew-update/, I did this:

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```

But no matter what I do, when I try to run

```
MacBookPro:~ pjs$ brew link youtube-dl
```

I get

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/opt
```

Same thing for linking any other formula.

Here are my permissions for /usr/local:

```
MacBookPro: /usr/local pjs$ ls -lah

total 104
drwxrwxr-x   26 pjs   admin   884B Aug 11 10:34 .
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root  wheel   442B Jul 21 17:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x   13 pjs   admin   442B Aug 26 13:42 .git
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   448B Aug 11 10:34 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   296B Jul 30 15:45 .yardopts
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   3.1K May 15 15:52 CODEOFCONDUCT.md
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   1.1K Oct 30  2014 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxr-x   96 pjs   admin   3.2K Aug 18 13:20 Cellar
drwxrwxr-x    3 pjs   admin   102B Jul 17 04:17 Frameworks
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   1.2K Jan 20  2015 LICENSE.txt
d-wx-wx-wx   11 pjs   admin   374B Aug 25 23:37 Library
d-wx-wx-wx    3 pjs   admin   102B Feb  1  2015 Qt
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin   2.3K Aug  3 01:26 README.md
-rw-rw-r--    1 pjs   admin    23K May 15 15:52 SUPPORTERS.md
drwxrwxr-x  454 pjs   admin    15K Aug 26 13:42 bin
d-wx-wx-wx   17 pjs   admin   578B Aug  6 01:03 etc
d-wx-wx-wx    9 pjs   admin   306B Feb  1  2015 git
d-wx-wx-wx   98 pjs   admin   3.3K Aug 25 23:36 include
d-wx-wx-wx  276 pjs   admin   9.2K Aug 25 23:36 lib
d-wx-wx-wx    4 pjs   admin   136B Feb  1  2015 libexec
d-wx-wx-wx   98 pjs   admin   3.3K Aug 26 13:42 opt
--wx-wx-wx    1 pjs   admin    88B May  6  2013 prince
drwxrwxr-x    4 pjs   admin   136B Aug  6 01:03 sbin
d-wx-wx-wx   42 pjs   admin   1.4K Aug 26 13:42 share
d-wx-wx-wx    5 pjs   admin   170B Jul 21 17:43 texlive
d-wx-wx-wx    6 pjs   admin   204B Aug  6 01:03 var
```

And here are my permissions for /usr/local/opt:

```
MacBookPro: /usr/local/opt pjs$ ls -lah

total 768
d-wx-wx-wx  98 pjs  admin   3.3K Aug 26 13:42 .
drwxrwxr-x  26 pjs  admin   884B Aug 11 10:34 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B May 16  2014 aspell -> ../Cellar/aspell/0.60.6.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Aug  5 22:25 autoconf -> ../Cellar/autoconf/2.69
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B May  3  2014 autojump -> ../Cellar/autojump/21.6.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Aug  5 22:25 automake -> ../Cellar/automake/1.15
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Jun 23 17:41 bdw-gc -> ../Cellar/bdw-gc/7.4.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    28B Aug 19 01:34 berkeley-db -> ../Cellar/berkeley-db/6.1.26
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B Aug  4 11:30 brew-cask -> ../Cellar/brew-cask/0.56.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug  4 11:30 cask -> ../Cellar/cask/0.7.2_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Aug 19 01:50 cmake -> ../Cellar/cmake/3.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Sep 27  2014 cmatrix -> ../Cellar/cmatrix/1.2a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Jul 20 00:31 cmus -> ../Cellar/cmus/2.7.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug 25 23:25 d-bus -> ../Cellar/d-bus/1.8.20
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 31 20:59 dict -> ../Cellar/dict/1.12.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Aug  6 01:03 dovecot -> ../Cellar/dovecot/2.2.18
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Aug 10 16:59 emacs -> ../Cellar/emacs/24.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    19B Aug 21  2014 faac -> ../Cellar/faac/1.28
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    19B May 16  2014 faad2 -> ../Cellar/faad2/2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Jul  1 23:50 fasd -> ../Cellar/fasd/1.0.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Aug 18 09:59 ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/2.7.2_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Dec 18  2014 flac -> ../Cellar/flac/1.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    27B May  9  2014 fontconfig -> ../Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Jul 17 04:44 freetype -> ../Cellar/freetype/2.6_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    19B Oct 30  2014 gdbm -> ../Cellar/gdbm/1.11
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B Jul 21 01:40 gettext -> ../Cellar/gettext/0.19.5.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 31 22:30 glib -> ../Cellar/glib/2.44.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug  5 22:25 gmime -> ../Cellar/gmime/2.6.20
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B May 16  2014 gmp -> ../Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B May 17 06:13 gnu-typist -> ../Cellar/gnu-typist/2.9.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug 18 13:20 gnupg -> ../Cellar/gnupg/1.4.19
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Aug 18 09:59 gnutls -> ../Cellar/gnutls/3.3.17.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B Aug  6 03:27 html2text -> ../Cellar/html2text/1.3.2a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Jul 17 04:31 hunspell -> ../Cellar/hunspell/1.3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B May 17 06:19 icu4c -> ../Cellar/icu4c/55.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    30B Jul 28 16:12 imagemagick -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.1-10
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Aug 26 00:35 isync -> ../Cellar/isync/1.2.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Dec 18  2014 jansson -> ../Cellar/jansson/2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    17B Jul 17 04:44 jpeg -> ../Cellar/jpeg/8d
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jan 20  2015 json-c -> ../Cellar/json-c/0.12
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B May 16  2014 lame -> ../Cellar/lame/3.99.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B May 16  2014 libao -> ../Cellar/libao/1.2.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B May 16  2014 libcue -> ../Cellar/libcue/1.4.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Jul 31 22:29 libffi -> ../Cellar/libffi/3.0.13
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    27B Jul 28 16:12 libgcrypt -> ../Cellar/libgcrypt/1.6.3_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    27B Apr 14 07:57 libgpg-error -> ../Cellar/libgpg-error/1.19
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Jul 31 20:58 libmaa -> ../Cellar/libmaa/1.3.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug 30  2014 libogg -> ../Cellar/libogg/1.3.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Jul 28 16:12 libpng -> ../Cellar/libpng/1.6.18
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B May 17 06:13 libtasn1 -> ../Cellar/libtasn1/4.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Jul 17 04:44 libtiff -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.0.4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Jul 17 04:44 libtool -> ../Cellar/libtool/2.4.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    28B Apr 14 07:57 libvo-aacenc -> ../Cellar/libvo-aacenc/0.1.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Apr 14 07:57 libvorbis -> ../Cellar/libvorbis/1.3.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Jul 13 23:43 libvpx -> ../Cellar/libvpx/1.4.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Jan 20  2015 libyaml -> ../Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B May 12  2014 lynx -> ../Cellar/lynx/2.8.8rel.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B May 16  2014 mad -> ../Cellar/mad/0.15.1b
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B Oct 18  2014 makedepend -> ../Cellar/makedepend/1.0.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Aug  2 03:05 mercurial -> ../Cellar/mercurial/3.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 31 03:19 most -> ../Cellar/most/5.0.0a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B May 16  2014 mp4v2 -> ../Cellar/mp4v2/2.0.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Aug  5 22:26 msmtp -> ../Cellar/msmtp/1.6.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    17B Aug 10 14:40 mu -> ../Cellar/mu/HEAD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B May 16  2014 nettle -> ../Cellar/nettle/2.7.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 17 04:17 node -> ../Cellar/node/0.12.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Aug  6 02:35 notmuch -> ../Cellar/notmuch/0.20.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    28B Aug  5 20:23 offline-imap -> ../Cellar/offline-imap/6.5.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    26B Aug  5 22:27 openssl -> ../Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Jul 20 23:38 pandoc -> ../Cellar/pandoc/1.13.2.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    19B Jul 19 18:58 pcre -> ../Cellar/pcre/8.37
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Sep 25  2014 pdfjam -> ../Cellar/pdfjam/2.08
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 31 20:55 perl -> ../Cellar/perl/5.22.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    29B Oct 12  2014 pianobar -> ../Cellar/pianobar/2014.09.28
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B May 16  2014 pkg-config -> ../Cellar/pkg-config/0.28
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Jul 17 04:17 python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.10_2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Oct 30  2014 readline -> ../Cellar/readline/6.3.8
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Jun  4 02:50 rmtrash -> ../Cellar/rmtrash/0.3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Aug 20 12:51 ruby -> ../Cellar/ruby/2.2.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Jul 31 03:19 s-lang -> ../Cellar/s-lang/2.3.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    30B Aug 11 10:34 screenbrightness -> ../Cellar/screenbrightness/1.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    29B Jul 31 22:30 sdcv -> ../Cellar/sdcv/0.5-2013-09-10
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    25B Aug 11 10:34 sqlite -> ../Cellar/sqlite/3.8.11.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    27B May  3  2014 ssh-copy-id -> ../Cellar/ssh-copy-id/6.6p1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Aug 13 01:46 surfraw -> ../Cellar/surfraw/2.2.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    22B Aug  6 02:35 talloc -> ../Cellar/talloc/2.1.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    24B Aug 21  2014 texi2html -> ../Cellar/texi2html/1.82
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    36B Jul 19 18:58 the_silver_searcher -> ../Cellar/the_silver_searcher/0.30.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    19B Jun 23 17:41 w3m -> ../Cellar/w3m/0.5.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 18  2014 wdiff -> ../Cellar/wdiff/1.2.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Apr 14 07:57 wget -> ../Cellar/wget/1.16.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    21B Jul 21 16:04 wordnet -> ../Cellar/wordnet/3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Aug 18 09:56 x264 -> ../Cellar/x264/r2555
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    23B Aug  5 22:25 xapian -> ../Cellar/xapian/1.2.19
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Jul  8 10:53 xvid -> ../Cellar/xvid/1.3.4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    18B Apr 14 07:57 xz -> ../Cellar/xz/5.2.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    20B Aug 21  2014 yasm -> ../Cellar/yasm/1.3.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pjs  admin    31B Aug 26 13:42 youtube-dl -> ../Cellar/youtube-dl/2015.08.23
```

How do I fix my Homebrew permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, a bunch of Homebrew's directories, including `/usr/local/opt`, do not have read permission. I believe Homebrew requires read permission as well as write permission to these directories. Try running this to grant the owner and group read permission:

```
$ chmod -R a+r /usr/local
```