# Unable to install HomeBrew, getting "illegal user name" error

Tags: permissions, homebrew

I'm trying to install HomeBrew on my iMac running OSX 10.11.1 El Capitan.

On the HomeBrew home page there is a short script in Ruby to paste into Terminal. When I did this, I got an error message as pasted below:

> chown: King_Bud: illegal user name Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo
>   /usr/sbin/chown King_Bud /usr/local/. /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib
>   /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1
>   /usr/local/share/doc

Based on the above message, I ran the first aid program in disk utilities and no permission errors were identified. But the above error code suggests some type of permission problem.

I see there was a post 2 years ago describing a similar error message but it sounds like this was occurring after HomeBrew was already installed, and pertained to installing new packages rather than the HomeBrew program itself. [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16432071/5610238)

Any thoughts about how to resolve the "illegal user name" problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem.

the chown error message was being created because my $USER environmental variable in my bash_profile was not matching the name of my logged-in user name as identified in Finder.

When I went into my bash_profile and edited the USER environmental variable so that $USER was the same as my logged-in user name in Finder, then I was able to successfully install HomeBrew using the pasted command from the HomeBrew home page.

Hopefully this posting will be helpful for anyone in the future who gets a similar error message while trying to install HomeBrew.

Comment: How do you go into your bash_profile to edit the USER environmental variable?

Comment: In my case I had a bash function which used USER as a variable internally. I declared the variable to be local with local USER = whatever to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your USER variable to your username by using the following command `export USER=<username>`