# Homebrew: Cannot link python

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm having an issue linking python in Homebrew. Here is the output:

`brew link python`

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13... Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Frameworks

When I `ls -al` on the contents of /usr/local (to see the permissions of Frameworks), I find there is no directory 'Frameworks'.

I'm hesitant to `mkdir Frameworks` in case it does so with the wrong permissions and doesn't connect it to other elements of the system.

Comment: What about `brew unlink python && brew link python`. If it need use `sudo`.

Comment: unlinking reveals that symlinks were present, but `brew link` still fails for the same reason. `sudo` doesn't work at all as Homebrew doesn't like using it: "Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system."

Answer (score 25):

Create the `Frameworks` directory and `chown` for itself

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Frameworks
$ brew link python
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the command: `sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local` courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions/16450503#16450503) elsewhere on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Cellar/
brew unlink python
brew link python
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative you can use pip

[How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-to-install-pip-on-macos-os-x)

Also, anaconda package is great

> https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem - brew still cannot link python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions