# XQuartz Gnuplot Mac Sierra trackpad issue

Tags: macos, gnuplot, macos-sierra, trackpad, xquartz

I'm using Mac Sierra and plot with XQuartz `Gnuplot` version 5.0. I can plot but after that not much else with the plot. I cannot zoom, double click to get coordinates to clipboard etc (and all the other keyboard commands don't work) as it is said in `gnuplot bind` that it should.

I have a trackpad without any extra buttons on it so I guess this is where the issue arises (I have checked/unchecked "emulate three button mouse" nothing helps). Any suggestions on how to fix this so I can zoom parts of the plot like they do on those d#mn smoothly working linux computers?
Btw not even a connected mouse does the job.

When I enter `gnuplot` in terminal and then `show mouse` (as suggested in the comments) I receive the following info

```
mouse is on
zoom coordinates will be drawn
no polar distance to ruler will be shown
double click resolution is 300 ms
formatting numbers with "% #g"
format for Button 2 is 0
Button 2 draws temporary labels
zoom factors are x: 1   y: 1
zoomjump is off
communication commands will not be shown
```

EDIT: I actually uninstalled and reinstalled gnuplot this time with

```
brew uninstall gnuplot
 brew install gnuplot --with-qt
```

and now I do have the zoom buttons on a gnuplot. For example when I write in terminal `gnuplot plot x` I can zoom and everything with the trackpad, good. But the issue that still remains is when I call on gnuplot from another code e.g. with a pipe. Then I do get the plot with the zoom buttons and all but when I click them nothing happens. Any ideas.

btw brew installing with qt was some trouble on Sierra I had to consult this page [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions).

Comment: How did you install gnuplot?

Comment: It was long ago but I think I used a wget line in the terminal. I'll check again.

Comment: I would suggest to use a package manager. I prefer https://brew.sh

Comment: What is the output of `show mouse`? Have you tried `set mouse verbose` to see if gnuplot receives any information about mouse events?

Comment: @bibi I remember trying all different methods, including brew, until it worked. So I'm not sure which one worked for me in the end, don't know if there's an easy way to check that.

Comment: Hi now I reinstalled with --qt and now when I write gnuplot plot sin(x) I can do all the zooming I want. But when I plot using persistent in a code I cannot zoom. I.e. when I use in a code gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");