# brew install git Error in Mac: Could not symlink share/man/man5/gitattributes.5

Tags: git, macos, github, homebrew, atlassian-sourcetree

Tried to update `git` on my Mac system (High Sierra 10.13.3) using

```
brew install git
```

which gives the output

```
$ brew install git
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/git-2.16.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring git-2.16.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/man/man5/gitattributes.5
/usr/local/share/man/man5 is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link git
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions and functions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

Emacs Lisp files have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/git
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.16.2: 1,496 files, 34.5MB
```

However, you can see that it has a problem with the `brew link` step. Attempting to fix it by running

```
brew link git
brew link --overwrite git
brew link --force git
```

gives the same error

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.16.2... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man5/gitattributes.5
/usr/local/share/man/man5 is not writable.
```

Anyone experienced this too and managed to fix it?

---

**Mac's Users and Group**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps running `brew reinstall git`?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Received the same error

Comment: This is maybe maybe because of the System Integrity Protection but normally it should not protect `/usr/local` try to deactivate it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled) and reactivate it after having changed the permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You have to fix the permissions with:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

It works well, if you are the only homebrew user on the system. It could cause problems if third party tools are waiting other permissions on `/usr/local`. But, I use this settings for years without problems. See [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) for details.

**But for this you must have the right to administer the computer.** In System Preferences -> Users & Groups, your user should have the checkbox "Allow user to administer this computer" checked.

Comment: Running the first line got me an error `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`. Any ideas?

Comment: See my updated answer. You must have the right to administer the computer, ask the owner of the computer.

Comment: I am using the Administrator account. Updated question with screenshots showing administrator rights

Answer (score 4):

If you are on High Sierra, the `/usr/local` is not writable (probably due to changes in [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204899)) but the contents are.  So you just need to modify the commands from the other answer to only target the directories within:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local/*
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew/*
```