# brew trying "migrating python3 to python" every time

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I believe the python environment is my Mac is a little bit mess up...
Every time I use brew, it will first do this:

```
==> Migrating python3 to python
==> Unlinking python3
==> Unlinking python
Error: Error occurred while migrating.
Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/share/python
Backing up...
Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/share/python
```

in my mac, I have:

- python2, which is referred by 'python', and it's installed by
  anaconda bundle.
- python3, which is referred by 'python3', and it's
  installed by brew.

Actually I create a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin for python3, which is the best way I can figure out to distinguish python/python3 in my machine......but recently it's just messed up...

I tried `find / -name "python3"`, and here is the result:

```
/Users/liuziqi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astroid/tests/testdata/python3
/Users/liuziqi/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/crcmod/python3
/Users/liuziqi/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3
/Users/liuziqi/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/crcmod/python3
/Users/liuziqi/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/python3
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/tests/testdata/python3
/usr/local/opt/python3
```

the python3 I previously used is `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3`, and I created a link to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Firstly, do you need to have both Python 2 and 3 on your machine? secondly, when you run `ls -la /usr/local/share/ | grep python`, who owns this file? It seems like Brew don't have permission to remove the file.

Comment: To be fair I should've asked this before. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to upgrade Python?

Comment: I do need both python2 and python3.  Actually I'm not doing anything with python, the problem is that when I use brew to install something else, it will first trying migrating python (maybe the that package have some dependency on python).

Comment: when i run `ls -la /usr/local/share/ | grep python`, the result is
`lrwxr-xr-x   1 liuziqi  admin    38  1 11 03:45 python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.14_2/share/python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix the permissions with:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

It works well, if you are the only Homebrew user on the system. It could cause problems if third party tools are waiting other permissions on /usr/local. But, I use this settings for years without problems. See [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) for details.