# Permission denied @rb_system when attempt to install httpd using Homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I want to install httpd using Homebrew but I keep getting this error -

```
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20180612-63207-1943ua6
```

I tried - `sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp` but that is not working

This is the current permission set for /tmp

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 _mysql  _mysql   256 Jun 12 18:39 tmp
```

Here is some information on my mac air

```
System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77) 
Kernel Version: Darwin 17.6.0
```

Even when I attempt to update ruby it gives me this error

```
[2018-06-12 18:13:32] requirements_osx_brew_libs_install
requirements_osx_brew_libs_install () 
{ 
    brew install "$@" --force || { 
        \typeset ret=$?;
        requirements_osx_brew_libs_error "installation";
        case "$_system_version" in 
            10.6)
                rvm_warn "
On OSX 10.6 instead of command line tools install:
    https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.6.pkg"
            ;;
        esac;
        return $ret
    }
}
current path: /Users/iivri.andre
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/iivri.andre/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/iivri.andre/.rvm/bin
command(10): requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml readline libksba openssl@1.1
++ brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml readline libksba openssl@1.1 --force
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20180612-55209-1k19y8s
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: did you try the install command with sudo instead of changing the permission of `/tmp` folder?

Comment: @Subash I did and it gave me

 `Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions