# error of "could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied" due to unstaged changes; in Homebrew while installing openJDK 8

Tags: java, git, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install OpenJdk 8 on a MacOS recently updated to Mojave. The install command was

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
```

It results in the following error:

```
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

But when I do 'git status' from within the /usr/local/Homebrew directory, it says 'nothing to commit, working tree clean'.

I looked at the hidden .git directories under/Homebrew. Before yesterday, it hadn't been touched in a year. I don't generally mess with it and haven't used it to install anything in awhile.

Answer (score 1):

The `cannot rebase` is a red herring—Git's gotten confused by the earlier failure into thinking it needs to rebase around it, but the earlier failure is not because of *changes*.  The actual problem is `permission denied`.

*That* problem means exactly what it says.  You, as yourself, have no permission to modify these files.  That means either you revoked your own permission, or you made these file as some other user.  See [How to fix homebrew permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16432071/1256452)