# ERROR 2002 (HY000) while using brewed mysql

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mamp, mysql-error-2002

I was using MAMP and have removed it completely from my MAC OS.
Post this,

1. I installed mysql5.7 using brew
2. Added mysql path to zshrc / bash profile
3. Started mysql service using `brew services start mysql@5.7`

Now when I try to access mysql on command line it gives me error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Where as I have already added socket path to **/tmp/mysql.sock** in my.cnf as well as tried creating symlink of same to ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
 but no luck.

Advice on same will be highly appreciated!

Comment: reading https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61011 and http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/82299/#position-7 are there no files to configure this globally? or maybe symlinking the file with `ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock` as a workaround

Comment: Did you have any previous installations of MySQL like MAMP or XAMP? Do you see the MySQL service running when you run `brew services list`?

Comment: Can you post the mysql error log content? At least the last 50 lines

Comment: your socket is at `/tmp/mysql.sock` ? Is this an absolute path? and the error searches at `/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`? or `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`?

Comment: @ChristosLytras - Yes as I was using MAMP so had mysql service from MAMP stack

Ron - Mysql service looks for socket on /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

this is a sign that the server did not really start.
Run:

```
ps aux|grep mysql
```

If you find a mysql server process , there are chances is not correctly installed.

the best is to uninstall, if you don't have anything important in the database and reinstall it again . You could try reinstall , but this is usually not fixing the issue.

```
brew services list 

brew uninstall mysql@YOUR_VERSION

brew install mysql@DESIRED_VERSION
```

Comment: you have a config file in the path somewhere. check the path and my.conf or search for every *.conf file that has the /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock in it.

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response but I have already checked configuration files related to mysql and could not find MAMP mysql.sock reference in it.
Is there any references in Apple start/load services that I need to modify to remove MAMP mysql reference?

Answer (score 0):

[1] I faced a similar issue a few weeks ago, the fix was changing my brew permissions. Try some of the answers [in this stackoverflow answer and the rest of the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46844441/4110233):

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

[2] Brew tells you a bunch of folders having permission issues and the fix for each of them. Run commands mentioned in `brew doctor` and it should work. Here is what **my brew doctor** had to say:

```
You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.  
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Frameworks /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log

And make sure that your user has write permission.
> chmod u+w /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Frameworks /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log
```

Comment: So you basically are saying that this question is a duplicate, why answer by linking another answer?

Comment: on "brew doctor" I don't get such suggestions to fix the permission issues.