# Homebrew fails on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur

I upgraded from Mohave to Big Sur and found that homebrew is not working any more. I installed the command line tools using the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

After I run `brew list`, I get the following error

```
~ brew list
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:21:in `<module:OS>'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:58:in `prerelease?'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `version'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `new'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:26:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:368:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
```

I tried by deleting the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and installing the `Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.3 beta` but still I am getting the same error. Is there any way to make brew work?

Comment: You should run `brew doctor`, fix the warnings, then try again. I don’t have any issue.

Comment: I faced the same error. The reason was the installed Homebrew's version was too old. I've run `cd /opt/homebrew; git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master` (my homebrew's dir is /opt/homebrew). It worked well for me.

Comment: Try resetting the xcode-select with `sudo xcode-select -r`
xcode-select -p should give `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
~

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try upgrading brew - this solved it for me.

```
brew upgrade
```

Comment: I encountered a handful of errors while running this on macOS Big Sur, including: File ownership, File permissions, Xcode outdated

Comment: I got the same error running this command.

Answer (score 188):

You should update brew;

```
brew update-reset
```

Comment: Works for me. The warning message is gone.

Comment: I was performing a brand new install, not an update, on Big Sur, and got a completely different error message, but the update-reset command worked for me. Thanks! Here was my error message in case it helps anyone else: "error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: I had to do this before I could do brew upgrade.

Comment: it works for me with only this command and without brew upgrade

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much for the help. I'd tried brew update but didn't know about the `update-reset` command. Cheers!

Comment: This should be the answer - cleared up the many problems brew was having.
After I ran `brew update-reset` I could then run `brew upgrade` and the many outdated packages installed successfully!

Comment: Probably the best solution. Works for macOS Monterey preview too, I can attest to that. After using this solution, perform `brew update-reset`.

Comment: Thank you! solved me a terrible issue with homebrew that I couldn't solve in any other way, including deleting and re-installing homebrew

Comment: Got this: `Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-boneyard... Username for 'github.com':`  .... I hit enter for it and password... Then later went in search of homebrew-boneyard and found this https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5820 ... The command `brew untap homebrew/boneyard` resolved that issue.

Answer (score 16):

I have solved my problem reinstalling brew with this script (install.sh):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then:

```
brew --version
```

output:

```
Homebrew 3.0.1
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 47e5d; last commit 2021-02-14)
```

Then just proceed with: xcode-select --install

Answer (score 11):

After upgrading brew

```
brew upgrade
```

I got the following message:

```
Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 11.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your Command Line Tools (CLT) or delete it if no updates are 
available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
```

According to the instructions I ran the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and again ran

```
brew upgrade
```

And finally it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You should update brew;

```
brew update-reset
```

Comment: it worked for me....brew upgrade wasn't working for me

Answer (score 6):

If you run `brew upgrade` still meet the error, maybe you should run `brew update` first.

My experience is:

```
1. brew update
2. brew doctor
3. brew upgrade
```

Comment: Warning: You are using macOS 11.0.
We do not provide support for this released but not yet supported version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
released but not yet supported version.

Answer (score 5):

I had MacOS Big Sur & nothing work for me even all [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)
But Except one thing works with me:

```
brew update-reset
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, "brew update" wouldn't work, "brew upgrade" also didn't work, did the following:

> brew update-reset

and then

> brew upgrade

Now working fine.

Cheers,

H

Answer (score 1):

When I follow @andrmu instructions, I received an error stating `Homebrew: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0.`. I had to first follow the instructions to clean upgrade my command line tools as per [the top answer on this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401899/homebrew-your-clt-does-not-support-macos-11-0), then it worked..

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After `brew upgrade` this did the trick to avoid tmp/mysql.sock error.
Use commandline command:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
```