# How do I install Apache Airflow on a Mac running Big Sur 11.0.1?

Tags: python, airflow, macos-big-sur

When I run `pip3 install apache-airflow` (I used `brew install python` to install the latest version of Python locally first), I get a number of errors while building wheels for psutil and setproctitle ending with the following:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for setproctitle which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Running the command with the `--use-deprecated legacy-resolver` indicated in [the note on the start page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html) has the same result.

What else am I missing that is preventing a successful install on Airflow on my machine?

Comment: which version are you installing?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13027

Answer (score 1):

Which python version do you have?
And what airflow version do you wish to install?

Since you said you've upgraded to the latest python version, I'm assuming you have 3.9.1. on your local machine.

[Airflow is not supporting python 3.9](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html) so you will need to use an older version of python.
I used python 3.7 to install airflow 1.10.10 (after which you can patch up to the latest version 2.0).

If using `pip` does not work (like what happened to me), try using `pyenv` to install python earlier versions. You might also (re)install zlib to get it to work `brew reinstall zlib bzip2`

*Since I had no `pyenv` installed, I had to go through the pain of upgrading homebrew to be able to do this ([see steps here in case you need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821648/homebrew-fails-on-macos-big-sur))*