# why Updating homebrew takes forever?

Tags: homebrew

this is my brew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.0.10-23-g5e0b08d
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HEAD: 5e0b08dd01bdce3523c7e095739641b6f33b902a
Last commit: 6 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 5e0b08dd01bdce3523c7e095739641b6f33b902a
Core tap last commit: 6 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
CPU: quad-core 64-bit icelake
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Git: 2.24.3 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.15.7-x86_64
CLT: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
Xcode: N/A
```

when I try to download something via brewing (for instance CAT)
terminal says "Updating Homebrew" and it takes forever

and brew doctor says

```
 "Warning: Suspicious https://github.com/Homebrew/brew git origin remote found.
The current git origin is:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core

With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't update properly.
You can solve this by setting the origin remote:
  git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew"
```

so I typed

```
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
 However, nothing happened
```

I am so frustrated from this. anyone can help?

Sorry for bad writing, English is not my mother-language :(

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and format it properly. To format code, select it all with your mouse then click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Thank you.

Comment: It really helps me to run Activity Monitor. That way, I can see that despite the silence something is actually happening. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840631/1346610

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Run brew update with debug option: `brew update -d`, to see what happens, where it hangs.

It might be caused by:

- the slow network.
- the waiting for the transferring of a big update.
- the firewall issue.

After you found the command where it hangs, try to run the exact command in the exact terminal, to debug the issue.

If it's related to a firewall issue, you can try to use a proxy server in the command line.

For example, you have a `http proxy server` available at `127.0.0.1:6152`. You can set it for `git`:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:6152
git config --global https.proxy http://127.0.0.1:6152
brew update -d
```

Or set the proxy for the whole command line(only for the commands that support proxy):

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:6152
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:6152
brew update -d
```

To undo the above proxy config, use:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Or

```
unset https_proxy http_proxy
```

Comment: I have the pleasure helping dozens of students every year use brew on their personal laptops. I can tell you, this is generally not caused by slow networks or large file downloads. Homebrew is predictably extremely slow (`brew update` takes several minutes) and buggy (works the first time for maybe 70% of students).

Comment: To developers: when composing a README instructing users on how to install your software, please don't list `brew install` as the first option. I enthusiastically initiated a brew install and have been sitting here for almost an hour watching homebrew update itself, count objects, compress objects, receive objects (whatever these things mean?)... and the simple plugin I was trying to install is still not installed. Reading a little further down in the README, I now realize I could have simply grabbed a .zip from GitHub's "Releases" and been done long ago. Keep it simple for users.

Comment: The proxy server thing worked like a charm, after much suffering thinking it was blocked on the "file touch" in other answers.  Adding -d made it look like it was blocked on the touched btw, even though the proxy was the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 110):

for me, it was holding on deleting a directory called TMP_FETCH_FAILURES, which didn't exist. so I have created it then rerun and it worked.

Comment: I don't have a directory but a file named TMP_FETCH_FAILURES, should I delete it and make a directory instead?

Comment: Thanks. To be clear I ran, `mkdir /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES is supposed to be a file, not a folder. Else, `brew upgrade` will throw some errors.

Comment: I used `touch /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES` instead of `mkdir` for the reason that @user1771485 pointed out. It worked.

Comment: The TMP_FETCH_FAILURES could also be located in: `/opt/homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES`. So please use `brew update -d` to see where the process gets stuck in your case.

Comment: on my mac M1, this fixed the issue : `mkdir /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES`

Comment: Upvoting for the refinements in the comments. After using the -d option, I settled on the following. There was still a delay after at one of the files, but only 90 seconds or so. <code>touch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES</code>

Comment: In my case, unfortunately, I see it hangs on this file but touching it or mkdiring it does not help at all (just so others don't feel nuts).  Tried it while it was stuck in parallel CI, and tried it before running update.

Comment: None of the steps above worked for me. I ran `brew update-reset` which takes about 4 minutes and it solved the issue for me. I found a fix from [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/14187#issuecomment-1334624189) on brews GitHub

Comment: I'm running an old macbook air and did brew update -d found I had to make a directory. Don't putz around with making the file because it kept hanging for me

Answer (score 18):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
rm -rf homebrew-core
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
```

Then run update again:

```
brew update -d --auto-update --verbose --force --debug
```

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253961400

Comment: this homebrew-core's git is really the culprit, but more importantly this solution flow is the best fix out of all answers

Comment: Not sure how this worked, but it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked for me. I also used `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git --depth 1` to avoid wasting a bunch of space on the repo history

Answer (score 8):

I also ran,

```html
mkdir /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/TMP_FETCH_FAILURES
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I've had the "hanging `brew update`" issue once, and tried everything suggested in the answers to this date, including:

- Turning off my Firewall — nothing changed
- Using a proxy server — `brew update` just failed to start fetching the repositories
- Messing with the `TMP_FETCH_FAILURES` file/directory — nothing changed
- Running `git remote-https origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core` — the command hanged
- Restarting macOS (that helps more often than one would expect) — nothing changed
- Running `brew cleanup`, `brew autoremove` — unrelated to this topic, was just trying things. Nothing changed in the behaviour of `brew update`
- Running `brew doctor` — nothing changed

The only thing that worked in the end is visiting https://brew.sh/#install and running the provided install script again. The issue just evaporated.

Comment: My clock was out of date when trying to install brew again, but after I corrected the clock, was able to reinstall brew. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me I just ran it again and it worked.  I did use -d but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Me also. I ran it after restarting mac and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was weird, I ran `brew update -d --auto-update --verbose --force --debug`, and when it hang I ran:

```bash
Criss-MacBook-Air:~ cris$ ps -a | grep brew
12161 ttys000    0:00.12 tclsh /opt/homebrew/bin/unbuffer brew update -d --force --verbose --auto-update
12163 ttys001    0:00.03 /bin/bash /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh update -d --force --verbose --auto-update
12402 ttys001    0:00.00 /bin/bash /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh update -d --force --verbose --auto-update
12462 ttys001    0:00.00 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git remote-https origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
12464 ttys001    0:00.06 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
13090 ttys002    0:00.00 grep brew
```

git-remote-https matched the job title in the shell window, too.

Then I just weirdly ran:

```bash
git remote-https origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
```

Which somehow kickstarted it out of its stall and then the whole thing started chugging along again, and finished really quickly.

WEIRD

Answer (score 0):

This is because apple tries to update many other unrelated things whenever you try to install something, but they make their download extremely slow to save bandwidth.
Unfortunately there is no way to resolve it except for getting a different OS