# MacOS home-brew failed on Big Sur Beta VM on VirtualBox

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur, brew-doctor

I am a newbie for MacOs development. I installed MACOS Big Sur beta on Virtualbox, installed Xcode. When I installed Homebrew and ran brew doctor. I encountered version invalid error. I tried many things according to other posts here. Didn't fix it.

```
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-iMac ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R xxxxxxxxxxx:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 44, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (42/42), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 44 (delta 23), reused 40 (delta 22), pack-reused 2
Unpacking objects: 100% (44/44), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
   6bb369916..5ea678bbc  master      -> origin/master
 * [new branch]          spdx-update -> origin/spdx-update
Updating files: 100% (2680/2680), done.
HEAD is now at 5ea678bbc Merge pull request #11824 from cnnrmnn/latest-head-kegs
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh
xxxxxxxxxxxxx-iMac ~ % brew doctor
Error: macOS '10.16' is invalid
xxxxxxxxxxxxx-iMac ~ %
```

The error is 10.16 is invalid
My MACOS is Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A4300b). Any tips for fixing this? I can't proceed with other brew install without getting through this. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821648/homebrew-fails-on-macos-big-sur

Comment: Thanks matt, I knew about this post, and tried every suggestion, didn't work. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, the problem is resolved:

1. go to Apple developer to download command line tools for Xcode. Please match the version your Xcode is. Install that after it is done.
2. then in terminal, run these few command lines:

- brew install --build-from-source gettext
- brew install --build-from-source pcre2
- brew install --build-from-source git

Note: running these will take a while, don't close.

After that I ran brew doctor, the error of invalid MacOS 10.14 is gone.
"Your system is ready to brew."

Comment: Also when I tried: sudo xcode-select --install, the 'finding software' window progress bar was not moving for more than 30 mins. The trick is to go to the apple developer page to download the command line tools for Xcode manually.