# Cannot run any flutter commands because of permissions, downloaded using homebrew

Tags: flutter, homebrew

I want to learn how to use flutter, so I downloaded it using `homebrew` on the M1 Mac.
Running `which flutter` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/flutter`

I tried running  `flutter doctor` which errors out. I'm not sure how to handle this.

````
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.```
````

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Homebrew permissions question that you happened to have bumped into with Flutter - which is good news, because Homebrew permissions issues are fairly well explored. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) has a ton of great answers.